# Error in MuiThemeProvider

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm facing a problem in a react project. When executing the project, I get the following error:

> "Failed prop type: The prop 'theme' is marked as required in
>   MuiThemeProvider, but its value is undefined."

This error is because of the MuiThemeProvider that I had to put to apply the drawer in my project. I searched in several forums and what I could see is that this is an error related to the version of the material-ui, but I could not solve it anyway.

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { withStyles } from 'material-ui/styles';
import MuiThemeProvider from 'material-ui/styles/MuiThemeProvider';
import AppBar from 'material-ui/AppBar';
import Button from 'material-ui/Button';
import IconButton from 'material-ui/IconButton';
import Drawer from 'material-ui/Drawer';
import Toolbar from 'material-ui/Toolbar';
import MenuIcon from 'material-ui-icons/Menu';
import TextField from 'material-ui/TextField';
import Paper from 'material-ui/Paper';
import Grid from 'material-ui/Grid';
import '../assets/scss/main.scss';
import img from '../assets/images/react.png';

const styles = theme => ({
  root: {
    width: '100%',
  },
  flex: {
    flex: 1,
  },
  menuButton: {
    marginLeft: -12,
    marginRight: 20,
  },
  inputProps: {
    step: 300,
  },
  button: {
    margin: theme.spacing.unit,
  },
  input: {
    display: 'none',
  },
  paper: {
    padding: 50,
    textAlign: 'center',
    border: '5px solid black',
    width: '100%',
  },
  paper1: {
    backgroundColor: 'red',
    marginTop: '13%',
  },
  img: {
    width: '45%',
  },
  appbar: {
    marginLeft: '-20.20%',
    marginTop: '-20%',
    width: '139.99%',
  },
});

function ButtonAppBar(props) {
  const { classes } = props;
  const state = {
    inputs: {},
  };

  const updateInputValue = (evt) => {
    state.inputs[evt.target.name] = evt.target.value;
    console.log(state.inputs);
  };

  const handleSubmit = (event) => {
    // console.log('handleSubmit', username, password);
    if (!event.target.checkValidity()) {
      console.log({ displayErrors: true });
    }
    event.stopPropagation();
    event.preventDefault();
    return 0;
  };
  return (
    <div className={styles.root}>
      <Grid container spacing={8} alignItems="center" justify="center">
        <Paper className={classes.paper}>
        <MuiThemeProvider>
          <AppBar position="static" className={classes.appbar}>
            <Toolbar>
              <IconButton className={classes.menuButton} color="contrast" aria-label="Menu">
              <Drawer />
                <MenuIcon />
              </IconButton>
            </Toolbar>
          </AppBar>
        </MuiThemeProvider>
          <img src={img} alt="React" className={classes.img} /><br />
          <form onSubmit={handleSubmit} noValidate>
            <TextField id="email" type="email" label="Usuário" className={classes.user} value={state.inputs.username} onChange={evt => updateInputValue(evt)} /><br />
            <TextField id="password" type="password" label="Senha" className={classes.senha} value={state.inputs.password} onChange={evt => updateInputValue(evt)} />
            <AppBar position="static" className={classes.paper1}>
              <Link to="/Orders">
                <Button type="submit" color="contrast">Login</Button>
              </Link>
            </AppBar>
          </form>
        </Paper>
      </Grid>
    </div>
  );
}

ButtonAppBar.propTypes = {
  classes: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
};

export default withStyles(styles)(ButtonAppBar);
```

My package.json:[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Aa74e.png)

Answer (score 5):

You need to pass a theme variable to MuiThemeProvider starting with v1.0.
You can find documentation at;

https://material-ui-next.com/customization/themes/#api

```
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import { MuiThemeProvider, createMuiTheme } from 'material-ui/styles';
import Root from './Root';

const theme = createMuiTheme();

function App() {
  return (
    <MuiThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <Root />
    </MuiThemeProvider>
  );
}

render(<App />, document.querySelector('#app'));
```

Comment: Also with material-ui v.1.0 MuiThemeProvider is optional. https://material-ui-next.com/customization/themes/#theme-provider

Comment: Getting error - Attempted import error: 'MuiThemeProvider' is not exported from '@material-ui/styles'.

Answer (score 2):

This is an extension of @mut's answer for those using a recent version (^3.0) of material-ui

```
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import MuiThemeProvider from '@material-ui/core/styles/MuiThemeProvider';
import createMuiTheme from '@material-ui/core/styles/createMuiTheme';
import Root from './Root';

const theme = createMuiTheme();

function App() {
  return (
    <MuiThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <Root />
    </MuiThemeProvider>
  );
}

render(<App />, document.querySelector('#app'));
```

Comment: still getting error: Warning: Failed prop type: The prop `theme` is marked as required in `ThemeProvider`, but its value is `undefined